# Switch back (to) use(ing)

Tags: phrases

I was trying to find some information on using "to + Ving" [The following](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38964/how-to-use-to-v-ing) was the closest I got, but I still have a question.

In the following snippet out of context:

> ...which causes him **to switch back to using** sophisticated verbiage ...

Which combination would be the most appropriate:

1. which causes him to switch back **to using** sophisticated verbiage
2. which causes him to switch back **using** sophisticated verbiage
3. which causes him to switch back **to use** sophisticated verbiage

Not a native language, so thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first option "which causes him to switch back to using sophisticated verbiage" is the only correct option.

In this sentence "using sophisticated verbiage" is a noun that you are switching back to. Consider "The peanut incident caused us to switch back to soy". You are clearly "switching back to" a noun.

This should make it clear that the "to" is necessary as it is part of "back to", not part of "to use" in this particular case. This rules out option 2.

The verb "to use" would be appropriate in different circumstances, but here we are "switching back to" a noun, which is why the gerund form of "use" is necessary. That's why option 3 doesn't work.